# RestKit + NSFetchedResultsController in a single view controller

Tags: core-data, restkit

I am using RestKit to pull User objects from a remote server and store them in core data.  I have a table view controller that is being populated by an NSFetchedResultsController with a fetch request that pulls User entities.  There is nothing unique about those User entities beyond the fact that they were queried within a given view controller, so I can't define a fetch that uniquely targets those just grabbed, but I only want to display those just grabbed in the table view (populated via the NSFetchedResultsController delegate methods).

Specifically, I have a view controller that displays the users a given user follows.  A second view controller displays those users that follow the given user.  They may be the same users, but more likely they aren't.  I also have a bunch of users in core data that were grabbed to populate an activity feed.  These users do not have any unique data that identifies those which are to be displayed in the activity feed vs the following list vs the followers list.  How do I make all 3 not cross populate while still using core data / NSFetchedResultsController?

What I'd like to do, but cannot seem to figure out, is make a child context in core data that doesn't automatically get populated with the data in the parent (but I do want the parent's schema).

Comment: Considered using relationships?

Comment: That's what I'm leaning towards.  Before I was using RK/CD for this type of stuff (pulling something from the server to display) I would simply grab and render what was returned w/out regard for client side relationships.

Comment: Well, RK does return the new items in the success callback. But if you do that, why bother with CD / FRC.

Comment: Yeah, that's my thinking too.  My ideal would be to create a child context of the RK object manager that pulls the schema but does not pull any of the data.  Then I do fetches against that "detached" child context.  But it doesn't seem to be supported in CD that I can find.

Comment: I wouldn't do that. I'd configure RK to update relationships on your user objects when you GET a set of followers for a user...

Comment: In the end I did create proper relationships and get them updating correctly.  If you provide a simple answer based on your first comment I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create relationships to store the users (or to provide the context information). RestKit can be configured to populate the relationships during mapping and then you can either use the relationship directly or in a predicate for your FRC fetch request.